# Searching string based off lookup table

Tags: sql

I have a lookup table with key words such as 45th street, hush creek, and gang. I need to find these words within the narrative column of the narrative table, and the output needs to be a separate table. The separate table needs to have the full narrative, the identifying record/number, and the key word that the narrative hit on. There is nothing linking these two tables together. The narrative table has over 230 million rows. How do I do this efficiently and effectively? Thank you.

The first table (lookup table):

```
Name1 varchar(250)
```

Example of data:

```
41 Boyz 
1 percenter gang 
0.01 gang 
1000 blk boys 
1000 blk boyz 
1000 blk crew 
1000 blk SMT
```

The second table (narrative table):

```
IncidentID: float
Narrative: varchar(max)
```

I need to find the narrative table records where the contents of the narrative column hit on the words from the look up table.  The results should be in a third table and should contain the IncidentID, Narrative (both from table two), and Name1 (from table one - the lookup table). The lookup word can be found anywhere in the narrative field.

The output would be:

```
Incident ID: 123145

Narrative: The officer came to the location of the 0.01 gang and met with the suspect.

Name1: 0.01 gang
```

Comment: Hi, please post the table structure of each table.

Comment: What's the specific database? The answer will probably heavily depends on which one.

Comment: Please add a small example and expected result. A few rows will go a long way.

Comment: Does you database support Full Text Search?

Comment: No. I added more information if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the situation:

- You have 230 million rows.
- You are looking for **multiple words** on articles, in **any order**, **letter case**, or even **abbreviations**.
- You probably want to find the matches in **reasonable time**. The quicker, the best. Is this an online query?
- You probably want to find **partial** matches, in case there are no full matches.
- You probably want to **rank the matches**, depending on how close the words are, and if they show up sequentially or not. Maybe check for lower/upper case, abbreviations, etc.

At this point you need to use a "full text search" solution. I usually recommend the PostgreSQL database since the functionality is fully available for free.

You'll need to try a few examples, and you'll get the idea pretty quick. In short the steps are:

1. Insert the text narratives.
2. Perform the indexing of the narratives. May take a few minutes or hours, depending on how large the data is.
3. Then search lots of times, producing fast [possibly ranked] results.

Later on, if you update the narratives, you'll probably need to index incrementally, the new/modified entries. This should be faster.

Comment: You are correct on the situation. Thank you for the details and recommendation.